# Server communication error handling in swift

Tags: swift4, swift5

In server communication, if we don't know what type of data is coming how can we pre-define whether it is (string or int) in Swift 4 and above?

I.e how can you assume whether data coming is string or int and how to handle errors for dynamic server data?

Comment: Please clarify the question with an example json and if possible what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

{"response":{"id":"353","specification":[{"item_value":3,"item_name":"Mileage"},{"item_value":"Used Car","item_name":"Condition"},{"item_value":"BMW","item_name":"Make"},{"item_value":"7-Series","item_name":"Model"},{"item_value":2019,"item_name":"Year"},{"item_value":"Both","item_name":"Preferred Selling Channel"},{"item_value":"asd","item_name":"Export Location"}],"description":"asd","lat_location":null,"isFavorite":false,"user_id":"156","title":"asd","seller_mobile":"971551909257","price":334,"location":"asd","date":"04 Nov 2019","long_location":null,"images":[],"result":1,"seller_id":78}}

**Check this out the modal class for the above json , In above json the specification array contain both integer and string value , we can easily access the value from it.**

```
struct GetResponse_DetailPage: Codable {
    let response: Response_DetailPage?
}



struct Response_DetailPage: Codable {
    let result: Int?
    let id: String?
    let sellerID: Int?
    let sellerMobile: String?
    let specification: [Specification_DetailPage]?
    let images: [Image_DetailPage]?
    let price: Int?
    let location, responseDescription, date, latLocation: String?
    let longLocation, title: String?
    let isFavorite: Bool?
    let userID: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case result, id
        case sellerID = "seller_id"
        case sellerMobile = "seller_mobile"
        case specification, images, price, location
        case responseDescription = "description"
        case date
        case latLocation = "lat_location"
        case longLocation = "long_location"
        case title, isFavorite
        case userID = "user_id"
    }
}
struct Image_DetailPage: Codable {
    let adImg: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case adImg = "ad_img"
    }
}
struct Specification_DetailPage: Codable {
    let itemName : String?
    let itemValue: ItemValue_DetailPage?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case itemName = "item_name"
        case itemValue = "item_value"
    }
}
enum ItemValue_DetailPage: Codable {
    case intege(String)
    case string(String)

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let x = try? container.decode(Int.self) {
            self = .intege(String(describing: x))
            return
        }
        if let x = try? container.decode(String.self) {
            self = .string(x)
            return
        }
        throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(ItemValue_DetailPage.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for ItemValue"))
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch self {
        case .intege(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        case .string(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
}
}
}
```

CHECK THIS OUT AND IF YOU HAVE PROBLRM THEN COMMENT ON IT